# Calling one of multiple inner functions from one of the outer variables function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

Given one of those:

```
def operations(x, y, z):
  def add(x,y):
    return x+y
  def sub(x,y):
    return x-y
  return z(x,y)
--------------------------------------------------
def operations(x, y, z):
  if z == add:
    def add(x,y):
      return x+y
  if z == sub:
    def sub(x,y):
      return x-y
  res = z(x,y)
  return res
```

I'm trying to call one of multiple inner functions from one of the outer variables function in python but I get this errors:

```
result = operations(10,5,add)
=>
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
--------------------------------------------------
result = operations(10,5,"add")
=>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I know i could use this solution:

```
def add(x,y):
  return x+y
def sub(x,y):
  return x-y
def operations(x, y, z):
  return z(x,y)
```

But for me it seems clearer to use *nested* functions.

I also read this:
[Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)
But it didn't really helped me.

Comment: Why do you think nested functions are clearer? You are *redefining* those functions every time you call `operations`. They are not defined once when `operations` itself is defined.

Comment: If you want to isolate them to their own namespace, use a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach unnecessarily redefines each of `add`, `subtract`, etc every time `operations` is *called*, not just once when `operations` is defined. If you want to isolate the individual operations to their own namespace, use a class.

```
class OperatorApplication:
    @staticmethod
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y
    
    @staticmethod
    def subtract(x, y):
        return x - y

OperatorApplication.add(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you making me realize about the unnecessarily redefining and for the _class_ trick!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I could come up with:

```py
def operations(x, y, z: str): 
    def add(x, y): return x + y
    def sub(x, y): return x - y
    # ...
    
    if z == 'add':
        return add(x, y)

    elif z == 'sub':
        return sub(x, y)

    # elif ...
    
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, {z} is not a valid function.')
        return
```

Let's break down the code:

```
    def add(x, y): return x + y
    def sub(x, y): return x - y
    # ...
```

This defined all of the functions we can use. *Note: I only made them one line to keep everything a bit more concise. This is not necessary.*

```
    if z == 'add':
        return add(x, y)

    elif z == 'sub':
        return sub(x, y)

    # elif ...
```

These are where we parse z, and return our values. These can go on as far as you want.

```
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, {z} is not a valid function.')
        return
```

This is just a base case for when a use enters an invalid operation.
For example, if you ran `operations(2, 2, 'not_real_function')` would return `Sorry, not_real_function is not a valid function.`.

Comment: Thank you for you elaborated answer but @chepner made me realize that my approach unnecessarily redefines each inner function every time outer function was called.